# Fail validation if one rule for any field fails

Tags: cakephp

How do you make validation in CakePHP stop if any single rule fails for any field?

I know about the 'last' property but that only stops validation for that field, I want it to stop completely.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure this is easily possible. May I ask *why*?

Comment: It seems conceivable to only *display* the first validation error, but all validation rules will be *checked*. Is this sufficient?

Comment: The question seems to be stating how validation works *already*. If *any* field in the form fails to validate, *none* of the fields in the record will be save()d, so it sure sounds like Cake already does what you want.

Comment: why would you even want to do that? the user should also be notified about other mistakes right away. so he doesnt have to post 5x to see all 5 mistakes etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was validating a picture upload in the model and then uploading it there and creating a user folder for the photo. Obviously I didn't know the user ID if the record failed the photo validation so the folder couldn't be created.

I have modified my validation to validate the upload and added a reference to the temporary uploaded file within the model class. I then wrote a custom afterSave() function to check if the user had uploaded an image when they registered, and if so to create the appropriate folders and move the image to a permanent location.

Thanks for the help.